# Compiling GCC 12.2.0 fails

Tags: linux, gcc

I've been following instructions from https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable-systemd/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html, but compiling GCC fails with the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a(md5.o): relocation 
R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: ../build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a(xstrerror.o): 
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE 
object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:3013: build/genchecksum] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-12.2.0/build/gcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4601: all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-12.2.0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1018: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Read the error message:  `relocation R_X86_64_32 against \`.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE 
object; recompile with -fPIE`